# Issue retrieving subdocuments from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following dataset:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59668a22734d1d48cf34de08"),
    "name" : "Nobody Cares",
    "menus" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "menu_123",
            "name" : "Weekend Menu",
            "description" : "A menu for the weekend",
            "groups" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Spirits",
                    "has_mixers" : true,
                    "sizes" : [ 
                        "Single", 
                        "Double"
                    ],
                    "categories" : [ 
                        {
                            "name" : "Vodka",
                            "description" : "Maybe not necessary?",
                            "drinks" : [ 
                                {
                                    "_id" : "drink_123",
                                    "name" : "Absolut",
                                    "description" : "Fancy ass vodka",
                                    "sizes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "_id" : "size_123",
                                            "size" : "Single",
                                            "price" : 300
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "mixers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "mixer_1",
                    "name" : "Coca Cola",
                    "price" : 150
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "mixer_2",
                    "name" : "Lemonade",
                    "price" : 120
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm attempting to retrieve a single drink from that dataset, I'm using the following aggregate query:

```
db.getCollection('places').aggregate([
    { $match : {"menus.groups.categories.drinks._id" : "drink_123"} },
    { $unwind: "$menus" },
    { $project: { "_id": 1, "menus": { "groups": { "categories": { "drinks": { "name": 1 } } } }  } }
])
```

However, it's returning the full structure of the dataset along with the correct data.

So instead of:

```
{
  "_id": "drink_123",
  "name": "Absolut"
}
```

I get:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("59668a22734d1d48cf34de08"),
  "menus": {
    "groups": {
      "categories": {
        "drinks": { "name": "Absolut" } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example. Any ideas how to just retrieve the subdocument?

Comment: Yep. **Flatten the array**. What you are trying to do here does not give you the advantages you seem to think it does. In truth it makes querying and updates far worse. So your "nesting" is actually better reflected here as "properties" of a single array of elements. This is easy to update and query, as opposed to the really unworkable form here. You seem misguided that "groups" and "categories" does something useful for you in this format. It does not. As "properties" however **"it would be useful"** But presently this is not good for performance or atomic updates.

Comment: Take a look at the $map operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain the deeply nested model then this call will produce the desired output:

```
db.getCollection('places').aggregate([
    { $match : {"menus.groups.categories.drinks._id" : "drink_123"} },
    { $project: {"_id": '$menus.groups.categories.drinks._id', name: '$menus.groups.categories.drinks.name'}},
    { $unwind: "$name" },
    { $unwind: "$name" },
    { $unwind: "$name" },
    { $unwind: "$name" },
    { $unwind: "$_id" },
    { $unwind: "$_id" },
    { $unwind: "$_id" },
    { $unwind: "$_id" }
])
```

The numerous unwinds are the result of the deep nesting of the `drinks` subdocuments.

Though, FWIW, this sort of query does perhaps suggest that the model isn't 'read friendly'.